# When I add prototype properties with an object literal then upstream direct protoype properties break. Why?

Tags: javascript

It seems to depend upon the order of prototype declarations. Here is the code:

```
function Person(firstname){
    this.firstname = firstname;
    }
//Person.prototype.middlename = "Charles"; //this line doesn't work here
Person.prototype = {
    constructor: Person,
    lastname: "Claus"
    }
Person.prototype.middlename = "Charles"; //this line works here
var person1 = new Person("Santa");
console.log(person1.firstname, person1.middlename, person1.lastname);
```

here is a link:
https://jsfiddle.net/tdz0yrs2/

Comment: Because you're overwriting the prototype with an entirely new object. The first middle name property existed on the old prototype but you replaced that object on the next line.

Comment: Thanks you all. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of statement:

```
Person.prototype = {
  // ...
};
```

**resets** the prototype property of the constructor to a completely new object. Any properties set prior to that point will remain on the *old* prototype object, but won't be present for newly-constructed objects.

The key point here is that an object literal assignment like that does not **add** properties — it creates a brand new object.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto what Pointy said.

You need to add your new functions to the prototype without overwriting the whole object:

```
Person.prototype.someFunction = function() { ... };
```

Or use something like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org)'s `extend` to mix new properties into the existing prototype:

```
_.extend(Person.prototype, { 
    // ...
});
```